# Install 3rd party macOS installer package

Tags: macos, installation, cmake, cpack

I am using CPack module in CMake to generate the product installer on macOS. I am trying to install a 3rd party macOS installer package as a prerequisite to our product installer. I tried -

```
add_executable(
    XYZ
    IMPORTED
)

set_property(
    TARGET XYZ PROPERTY
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/import/redist/XYZ.pkg 
)

install(
    IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS
        XYZ
    COMPONENT
        XYZ
)
```

However, this doesn't install the XYZ.pkg though it is part of my final product installer pkg file. Is this the correct way to embed and install 3rd party installer package from my product package installer ?

**Edit:** Instead of executing the XYZ.pkg installer to install it's components, my product installer is copying it to my product's destination folder. I was expecting to chain the install instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [CPack `IMPORTED_RUNTIME_ARTIFACTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-imported-runtime-artifacts) , I see it is designed for copying files, not executing them. That means the approach you have taken will not execute the `XYZ.pkg` package installer, but will package it into your product's `.pkg` installer.

If you wish to chain installers, you would typically use a post-install script that is executed once your package is installed. That script would then run the `XYZ.pkg` installer.

You can specify a post-install script (for instance, `postflight.sh` + `chmod 755`) using the `CPACK_POSTFLIGHT_SCRIPT` variable in CMake, [as seen in this thread](https://cmake.cmake.narkive.com/9JeMvu18/cpack-packagemaker-osx-post-install-script). Below is a simplified example.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
installer -pkg $PWD/XYZ.pkg -target /
```

In your [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variables-common-to-all-cpack-generators), set the `CPACK_POSTFLIGHT_SCRIPT` variable to point to your script.

```
...
include(CPack)

# specify your postflight script
set(CPACK_POSTFLIGHT_SCRIPT "/path/to/postflight.sh")
...
```

Do copy the `XYZ.pkg` into a location that the `postflight.sh` script can reference, or modify the `postflight.sh` script to locate `XYZ.pkg` appropriately.

Once your package is installed, the `postflight.sh` script should be executed, and it will run the `XYZ.pkg` installer. That should achieve the chained installation behavior you are looking for.

---

> I had a slightly different solution where post install script of my product installs the dependency using the exact command you mentioned.
> Unfortunately, our team was looking for a more standard solution.
>
> We ended up doing:
>
> 1. Modify our package distribution.xml to include `XYZ.pkg` info.
> 2. CPack builds our package (i.e., `PRODUCT.pkg`).
> 3. From post build script (`CPACK_POST_BUILD_SCRIPTS`), expand the `PRODUCT.pkg` using `pkgutil`. 4. Using the `productbuild`, include the expanded `PRODUCT.pkg, XYZ.pkg`.

Indeed, manipulating the package directly provides a more "native" approach for handling macOS installer packages.

By altering the `distribution.xml` and rebuilding the package using `productbuild`, you are essentially creating a "meta-package" that encompasses both your own product and the third-party dependency (`XYZ.pkg`). That ensures a more streamlined installation process and is generally more robust than relying on post-install scripts to install additional packages.

The use of [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) to expand the `PRODUCT.pkg` and `productbuild` to reassemble it, along with the third-party package, is a particularly effective way to achieve this. That approach has the advantage of integrating tightly with the macOS installer system, making it more predictable and potentially less prone to errors compared to a script-based approach.

Comment: Thank you. I had slightly different solution where post install script of my product installs the dependency using the exact command you mentioned. Unfortunately, our team was looking for a more standard solution. We ended up doing -

1. Modify our package distribution.xml to include XYZ.pkg info.
2. CPack builds our package (i.e., PRODUCT.pkg).
3. From post build script (CPACK_POST_BUILD_SCRIPTS), expand the PRODUCT.pkg using pkgutil.
4. Using the productbuild, include the expanded PRODUCT.pkg, XYZ.pkg.

Comment: I will wait and see if there are any more responses coming. If not, I will accept yours :)

Comment: @Mahesh Good alternative method. I have included it in the answer, with a comment of my own.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're using CPack in CMake to generate a product installer on macOS, and you want to include a 3rd party installer package as a prerequisite, here's what you can do. First, make sure you have the XYZ.pkg file in your project directory. Then, in your CMakeLists.txt file, add the following code to install the XYZ.pkg as a component:

```
# Install the XYZ component
install(
  FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/import/redist/XYZ.pkg
  DESTINATION /path/to/install/XYZ
  COMPONENT XYZ
)
```

Next, set up CPack to include the XYZ component by adding the following line to your CMakeLists.txt:

`set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL XYZ)`

Finally, configure CPack to use the PackageMaker generator by adding this line:
`set(CPACK_GENERATOR "PackageMaker")`

When you run cpack to generate the product installer, the XYZ.pkg will be included as a component in your installer. That way, when users install your product, the XYZ.pkg will be installed as well. Just make sure to adjust the paths and destinations according to your project setup.